# How do I save a custom Cursor to a file while keeping the original quality of cursor drawing?

Tags: c#

I tried to save a custom Cursor to a file. 
This is the function that I am using to draw the cursor:

```
    public Cursor CursorDraw()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(140, 25);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Green,3), 0, 0, 20, 20);
        return CreateCursor(bitmap, 3, 3);
    }
```

It makes a nice looking circle Cursor.
I also have a save function:

```
   void SaveCursor()
    {
        //YOUR CURSOR

        Cursor cr = CursorDraw();
        //GET ICON FROM YOUR CURSOR HANDLE

        Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(cr.Handle);

        //WRITE TO FILE STREAM
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\data\test.cur", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        ico.Save(fs);

        //TESTING       
    }
```

The output == > test.cur, 
but the drawing that is saved looks bad.
So how could I save with the same quality and shape of the orginal bitmap. 
Thanks

Comment: Icon files aren't bitmaps, they typically have a resolution of 16x16, etc etc, so your 140x25 will probably be converted to either 128x128 or 256x256 so it won't look good at all.

Comment: but the background became balck

Comment: That sounds right, that's typically the the opaque color.

Comment: can i make it transparent?if yes how

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the Interpolation Mode.

Add this to set it:

`g.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`

And it should fix the issue.

Comment: the same issue.

Comment: I expect it's the same thing but on the `Icon` or `Cursor`. You haven't included `CreateCursor()` so I don't know what that is doing.